# JavaScript - RegEx that matches any number between 0.01 and 99

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a form where there's an **"Interest Rate"** Field which has accept values between 0.01 and 99.00

I've already looked a RegEx Up from [0.01 to 99.99 in a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727052/0-01-to-99-99-in-a-regular-expression). This almost does the trick. The only challenge that I'm getting is to make it to NOT MATCH numbers from 99.01 to 99.99.

I've updated it to cater to up to 10 digits after the decimal point.

**Test Data:**

Should only match numbers between 0.01 and 99.00

Should Not Match

- 00.00
- 100.134234
- 99.01234 // this is matching, but should not match with my current RegEx.
- 100

Should Match

- 0.01
- 0.10
- 1.233
- 3.20
- 4.655
- 5.112
- 99.00
- 99.0

I've already created a [RegEx101 Sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/R63oyb/2) which I feel might be useful.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/GLiWR9/1

Comment: This works too. Thank you @WiktorStribiżew for the alternative :)

Comment: This one works for the `99.0` case too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning, add a negative lookahead for 99 followed by anything but `.00`:

```
(?!99\.0*[^0\n])
```

https://regex101.com/r/R63oyb/10

excluding `99.01` and `99.10` and so on, but permitting `99.00` and `99`.

Comment: @SiddAjmera `/^(?!99\.0?[^0]$)(?=.*[1-9])\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{0,10})?$/.test('99.0')` results in `true` as desired, right?

Comment: I guess I had too many RegEx101s opened and probably checked the wrong one. My bad. Apologies. All good :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my approach:

```
^(?:(?![0.]+$|99)|(?=(?:99|99\.0+)$))\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/R63oyb/9)

- `\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?` Matches 1-2 digit numbers optionally followed by a decimal point and some digits
- `(?:(?![0.]+$|99)|(?=(?:99|99\.0+)$))`

  - `(?![0.]+$|99)` Tests if the number is only formed by `0` and `.` or starting with `99`, fails it. This eliminates `0` and `99`
  - `|(?=(?:99|99\.0+)$)` Unless the number is pure `99` or `99` followed by a decimal point and a bunch of `0`s, let it pass.